# Apache HTTPD Websocket Tunnel Plugin Error

Tags: apache, spring-websocket, mod-proxy-balancer

My websocket connection fails to connect when connecting through Apache ws tunnel plugin intermittently. The connection always works when hitting the app servers directly.

I see the below errors.
Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line

WebSocket connection to 'ws://host' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 0 
and sometimes
WebSocket connection to 'ws://host' failed: Unrecognized frame opcode: 12

and at times 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line does not end with CRLF ui-toolkit-vendor.js:21965

Infrastructure
Apache HTTPD 2.4.9 with mod_proxy_wstunnel and mod_proxy_balancer modules

Answer (score 0):

The ws tunnel module ported with 2.4.9 version has several bugs which have been later fixed in the 2.4.12 build. Please find the excerpt from the SVN log.
Revision 1587075 - (view) (download) (annotate) - [select for diffs] 
Modified Sun Apr 13 18:41:05 2014 UTC (11 months, 3 weeks ago) by covener 
File length: 20119 byte(s) 
Diff to previous 1587057 (colored)
several related mod_proxy_wstunnel changes that are tough to pull apart:

- make async websockets tunnel opt-in
- add config for how long we block a thread in asynch mode
- add config for a cap on the synchronous path
- avoid sending error responses down the upgraded tunnel